# Deploying a war to Jetty with CDI

Tags: maven, jetty, jndi, cdi

I have a maven project in IntelliJ where I am trying to deploy a war file to a jetty container. The purpose of this is for a quick integration test of some of the functionality in said war file.

Since out of the box Jetty does not come with CDI or JNDI, I am trying to add support for these but running into some issues. For example, I get the following error on startup:

```
15:30:50 [34mINFO [0;39m o.a.s.c.CdiObjectFactory - [lookup]: Checking for BeanManager under JNDI key java:comp/BeanManager 
15:30:50 [39mDEBUG[0;39m o.a.s.c.CdiObjectFactory - [lookup]: BeanManager lookup failed for JNDI key java:comp/BeanManager
```

I have included the weld-servlet jar in my pom and also added the weld listener to the web.xml, however it still does not work. I am using Jetty 9. Any ideas?

> pom.xml
>
> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
>         <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
>         <version>2.0.4.Final</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```
>
> web.xml
>
> ```
> <listener>
>   <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
> </listener>
> ```

```
<resource-env-ref>
   <description>Object factory for the CDI Bean Manager</description>
   <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
   <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

Comment: Found the problem. It turns out that the class loader was getting confused on where to get the appropriate WELD support. I had weld-servlet as specified in my pom, but the war that I was deploying also had other jars that bring in weld as well.

I separated the project that was starting jetty out into a new IntelliJ project and it worked just fine.

Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following config works for me on Jetty 8.x and 9.0.x (not 9.1+ for the moment)

Here are the config needed :

Add the dependency in Pom.xml

```
....
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
....
```

note the fact that i'm using `weld-servlet`dependency which contains all needed Weld and CDI classes.

In `jetty-env.xml` you declare the JNDI ressources

```
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure id="webAppCtx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="BeanManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>
            <Ref id="webAppCtx"/>
        </Arg>
        <Arg>BeanManager</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="javax.naming.Reference">
                <Arg>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</Arg>
                <Arg>org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory</Arg>
                <Arg/>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

in `web.xml` you add the listener and expose the JNDI resource :

```
...
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
...
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>
        javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
    </resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
...
```

And eventually if you want to be able to inject bean in servlet you need to ask Jetty to expose some of its inner class by creating the following `jetty-web.xml` file in your `WEB-INF` directory

```
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="serverClasses">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.Decorator</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

Dont miss the `-` in `<Item/>`, it's the way to tell Jetty that a class is no more an inner class and can be seen by the webapp. With that Weld will be able to decorate Jetty inner servlet class to add CDI Injection support in it.

**Bonus : using the jetty plugin for Maven**

It's quite easy, you'll only have to add a `run`profile to your `pom.xml`like this

```
<profile>
    <id>run</id>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean jetty:run-forked</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.7.v20131107</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stopPort>1353</stopPort>
                    <stopKey>quit</stopKey>
                    <contextXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml</contextXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

After that you'll only have to type `mvn -Prun` to build your app, launch Jetty and deploy the app in it.

Comment: Careful: the XML with `<Set name="serverClasses">` actually removes all of the webapp classloader isolation. Using that technique, you just overwrote the entire serverClasses array with 1 entry, making everything from the server classloader now visible to the webapp. (a no-no in servlet spec terms)

Comment: The `serverClasses` caused error in the latest Jetty 11.

Answer (score 1):

Jetty 9.1.0+ requires Weld 2.2.0+

See: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1561