# Using CDI with Jersey 2.x Deployed on Jetty

Tags: jetty, cdi, jersey-2.0

I am trying to convert a Jersey 2.x project that was originally written using Grizzly (embedded Glassfish) to not use Grizzly. The app will be deployed to a Jetty server (9.3).

As soon as I got rid of all the Grizzly references, added my web.xml, etc... I am getting a bunch of errors that all my references of @Inject are not working.

The original app was using Weld to handle all the CDI stuffs; I was under the impression CDI was built into Jetty, is this not the case?

In my POM I am including all of the jersey server deps. The first place I am getting an error is in a file that does Oauth Request Filtering... it implements ContainerRequestFilter and has an annotation of @Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION). Inside of this class I have an @Inject of some classes to do look ups.

```
@Inject
private OauthManager manager
```

When Jetty starts it's telling me that it cannot find OauthManager to inject into this class.

Answer (score 0):

CDI is not built into Jetty.

CDI is provided by the the Weld project, which works just fine on Jetty.

See prior answer on details on how to set this up.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20505983/775715

Comment: So, yeah... I was able to get the app deployed... and it seems to work, however, whenever I try to access anything... it tells me there's more than one @RequestScope context laying around... that's got me kind of buggered.